# Expected Value with Variable Probability

Tags: probability, combinatorics

The following is well-known: given a coin that lands on heads with probability $p$ and tails with probability $1-p,$ what is the expected number of flips to have the coin land on heads? The answer to this is intuitively obvious (and easy to prove with a recurrence): $1/p.$ One faulty way of arriving at this answer is to look at the expected number of heads after $n$ flips - obviously, this is just $np.$ Then we want this expected number to be $1,$ which gives $n = \frac{1}{p}.$

The first flaw is that $n$ has to be an integer for this to make sense anyway; the other is that this is not true in general. This led me to think about a problem as follows (as a counterexample to the logic above). Consider a coin that lands on heads with probability $\displaystyle\frac{1}{2^n}$ on the $n$-th flip. What is the expected number of flips to have the coin land on heads?

If we were to apply the same logic as above, we would see that the expected number of flips is infinite. However, if we just calculate directly:

$E[X] = \displaystyle\frac{1}{2}\cdot 1 + \frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{4}\cdot 2 + \frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{3}{4}\cdot\frac{1}{8} \cdot 3 + \ldots = \frac{1}{2} +\sum_{i=2}^{\infty}\frac{\prod_{j=1}^{i-1}(2^j-1)}{2^{i(i+1)/2}}\cdot i,$ which converges by the ratio test. My question is: does this sum evaluate nicely?

Addendum: Evaluating this sum with wolfram alpha gives an answer of around $1.08,$ which still makes little sense to me since if the probability of heads is $1/2$ every time, the expected number of flips is $2.$ Maybe I've messed up my summation?

Comment: For first paragraph, it is really nicer if you see it in terms of geometrical distribution.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean? I was just giving faulty reasoning. The nicest proof that I know is as follows: $E[X] = \frac{1}{p} \cdot 1 + \frac{p-1}{p} (E[X] + 1),$ whence $E[X] = \frac{1}{p}.$

Comment: Pardon me, I have totally misunderstood the context, I thought you were seeking for a proof that $E(X)=\frac{1}{p}$.

Comment: Note that $E(X)$ **is** infinite because $P(X=+\infty)>0$. The sum of the series you are considering is $E(X;X<+\infty)$.

Answer (score 2):

Well if you're just after a numerical evaluation, tools like Wolfram-alpha can be really useful. So pasting :

> sum ((product (2^j-1), j=1 to i-1)*i*1/(2^(0.5*i*(i+1))) , i=2 to infinity)

In [Wolfram-alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com), will result in the infinite sum you're looking for, which by Wolfram's calculations is $0.585106$ well the $+0.5$ is trivial :)

**EDIT** Now with the fixed values it is indeed $\geq1$.

Comment: ah actually your post made me realize a mistake in my sum because an answer $<1$ doesn't make sense :)

Comment: @lyj you're welcome, well I've used some more of the Wolfram magic and now it is $\geq 1$ as you've suspected, enjoy :)